# forcing css file to work in a div only

Tags: css

I have a project and want to embed some external css file without compromising sites css files.

Is there any way to make css file (without changing everyline) work in a div like an iframe?

Comment: You can do it by sass.

Answer (score 3):

***"Is there any way to make css file (without changing everyline) work in a div like an iframe?"***

NO. ([At least not for now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped)...)

Css is applied to the whole page, and there is no way to limit it to only apply to a certain context without messing with it (injecting your context's `#id` to the beginning of every selector in the CSS), or as you said, creating an `iframe` that basically has its own scope.

Sorry...

Comment: Added the note :-) thanks @George

Answer (score 0):

You say that you need a different CSS to work only for a particular div, in this case, you can make a css only for a particular `div`.

```
#div1
{
//css here
}

<div id="div1">
<!-- Only CSS for div1 would be displayed here.
</div>

<div id="div2">
<!-- CSS of div1 won't affect this
</div>
```